# Finding books about generating functions like this one?

Tags: integration, factorial, products

$\prod_{1}^{n}\left ( \int_{0}^{1}x^n dx\right ) =\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

I am looking for topics to search to find more gen. functions like these?

No need for a long explanation, I'm going to go read it anyways.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see how that's a generating function?

Comment: Ok great, what is what I am doing called in the "math world"

$\prod_{1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1}log(x^n)dx=(-1)^nn!$

Here is another example.

Comment: OP here. I am really sorry that I have angered the Math Great's on High. I guess to most readers in this forum my question felt like a run-of-the-mill homework problem. If they would have worked out the identity they could have found my error. (15 seconds on an HP Prime) Anyways watch this new video by an awesome channel called Flammable Maths on the "Dividorial". (real loud sometimes turn-down!) Also, I only recently obtained an Associate in Math Secondary Education May 2020 so I am kidda stupid in math. This is/still is no homework problem I have seen, but super cool if you really love Math.